# What's the sizeof the virtual function table pointer?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

In single inheritances, is the size of a pointer to virtual table always equal to the size of a `void*`? Say,

```
class vft { virtual ~vft(); }
assert (sizeof(vft) == sizeof(void*));
```

Would that assertion always be true?

Comment: I think it is at least implementation (compiler) dependent, so not ALWAYS true. Although it might be reasonable to assume, I'm sure you get into dangerous territory when messing around with the vptr yourself.

Comment: There is no such thing as a virtual table or a virtual table pointer (in relation to C++). Asserting the existence of such a thing is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ ISO Standard says nothing about *virtual function table pointer* in the first place. A Compiler may follow this mechanism to support runtime-polymorphism or can come up with any other which doesn't even involve `vptr`. Its entirely upto the compiler writers. Since the Standard doesn't say anything about `vptr`, how can it say about its size? No way. The conclusion is: what you're doing (or assuming) isn't gauranteed by the language. However, for a compiler, it *might* be always true.

<sup>As a sidenote, for your compiler, how can you conclude that `sizeof(vft)` will be equal to `sizeof(vptr)`? It could very well be that `sizeof(vft) > sizeof(vptr)`. I don't claim that though.</sup>

Comment: Oh, `vft` is just a random name :)

Comment: @neuront: I know that its "random" name. My point was, why should the size of class, be equal to the size of `vptr`? In your example, `vft` is a class name.

Answer (score 3):

No, Virtualism is implementation defined. It is an compiler implementation detail.
So you cannot say that will be true always.

Also, You should refrain yourself from writing any code(like the one in Question) that assumes an detail that is left open by the Standard as an compiler implementation detail, Because that makes your code not 100% portable across compilers & might even fail drastically on some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the facts that everyone else already pointed out, I feel like the standard does give some guarantees.  Namely, for `class vft { void* a, b; virtual ~vft(); }` then `sizeof(vft) > sizeof(void*)`.  I'm pretty sure the standard guarantees that much at least, virtual functions or no.

Answer (score 0):

"Would that assertion always be true?" Depends on what you mean by "always".

As others have already pointed out, this is an implementation detail that is subject to change even with different versions of the same compiler. The C++ standard says nothing about it, so you can't rely on it.

On the other hand, I've never seen a compiler where this wouldn't be true.

Comment: I have. In the early days Virtual tables were still be tested and other techniques were used.